# Unable to simulate AD8232 SPICE model in LTSpice

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice

[image]I downloaded the SPICE model of the IC from the website.
I can put a link to the webpage if anyone comments that I should, I am not because the last time I did so my post was flagged.
I am putting a screenshot of the error below and what the simulation directives look like.
[image: This is what the SPICE directive looks like]
[image: The Error]

Comment: Have a look at [this thread.](https://groups.io/g/LTspice/topic/error_messages_for_tlc555/73376583?p=)  I'm not familiar enough with LTspice to be sure the advice is good.  If the link helps you, then you can post an answer describing how you fixed your problem.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're performing any simulation, you're simply loading the subcircuit and then click "run". This suggests that not only you don't know how LTspice works, but you don't know basics of SPICE usage, either. Unless I am wrong (my apologies if so!), in the most neutral tone possible, I would recommend learning about those, first (at the very least some SPICE generalities).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen so there is the option of right clicking and pressing create symbol option. That is also not working.

Comment: @ShridharSharma So not only you're changing the subject, you're also confirming my words, because you're not right-clicking where you should be. I won't make any futher comments.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I dont even want to know how you arrived at those conclusions.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen So let me get this straight you speak about talking in a neutral tone but that is a facade because clearly you somehow have a sense of entitlement to respect because you can answer which according to what you are implying is a basic error? Am I getting this right? Should have gone into sales and marketing

Comment: @ShridharSharma No, you are not getting it right at all.  "Clearly", your assumptions are very bad.  Here is an article and a video to hopefully help you along: 
https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-simple-steps-to-import-third-party-models.html  
///  
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajcYYwoHF0g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem was literally right clicking on the .SUBCKT and not the name of the sub-circuit which I thought was the name of the IC and then selecting create symbol.